# Where to find free, high-quality, letterpress/woodblock type fonts?

Tags: font-recommendation

I may be asking for too much but...I'm trying to find fonts that look in the style of letterpress and/or woodblock type printing. I'm only a graphic designer in my free time, and am just working on a personal project, so I'm on a budget (free if at all possible). Google is littered with links to sites with thousands of ugly, free fonts. I'm afraid the selection of fonts that I'm trying to find are not as prevalent as many of the other fonts available.

Where might I be able to find affordable, letterpress type fonts?

Comment: "Free time"? -- I had one of those, once. Long time ago.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I designed (er...well, I didn't design them...but traced) some wood type for Chank many years ago:

https://www.chank.com/shop/detail/3/font_packs/19/blinctype_letterpress_fontpack/

Tho...$250 for the set might not be close enough to free.

This company sells scans of wood print scans:

http://www.withoutwalls.com/

A nice set at Veer:

http://marketplace.veer.com/font/weathered-woodtype-pack-det0000303

You can often find Creative Commons licensed stuff for on Flickr:

http://www.flickr.com/groups/woodtype/

A few wood-type-esque fontsquirrel options:

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/list/keyword/wood%20type

Wood Type Revival has some VERY affordable options (around $15 each):

http://www.woodtyperevival.com/t/fonts

Not full type sets, but Briar Press has a nice online set of one-off initial caps and decorations for download:

http://www.briarpress.org/cuts/

The Lost Type Foundry is a newer foundry that's adopted a pay-what-you-like model which is really nice. Not wood-type per se, but some that are evocative of the era:

http://losttype.com/about/

But your best option (or, at least, the option that's most fun) would be to find a local shared book arts/printing studio/organization and print your own! Looks like Portland has this one:

http://www.em-space.org/em-space/?page_id=323

Comment: That's an expert answer!

Answer (score 0):

I have a wide range of woodblock fonts available on my Creativemarket shop at: https://creativemarket.com/Kitch22