# What is the best way to obtain fonts to use for something commercially produced?

Tags: fonts, licensing

I am looking for fonts to use for a bound planner of sorts that I am making for myself, but possibly to sell in the future.  I've downloaded a few free fonts, with SIL open licenses, can I use these? Thanks!

Comment: Have you read the licence (Open Font Licence, or OFL) that comes with them? It even [has a FAQ](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?item_id=OFL-FAQ_web#c26665c2) that answers your question quite adequately.

Comment: The best way is to purchase them from a dedicated, hard-working font designer / foundry.

Comment: Related: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/3778/where-to-find-free-high-quality-letterpress-woodblock-type-fonts :: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/15926/where-do-professional-designers-go-to-look-for-typefaces

Answer (score 2):

The full license of OFL can be found [here](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?item_id=OFL_web). SIL OFL license is a somewhat permissive copyleft license. Itis unfortunately a [viral license](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viral_license). So it is not entirely suited for every action. It is however not similarly viral as using GPL:ed components as it only affects the font itself and leaves rest of your stuff intact.

**To be clear.** In the usecase that you describe it seem perfectly fine. But i am not a lawyer, and not your lawyer so dont take this as legal advice.

There are other permissive font licenses other permissive font licenses such as:

- Apache 2.0 (example [Caladea](https://fontlibrary.org/en/font/caladea))
- CC-BY (example [Grundschrift](https://fontlibrary.org/en/font/grundschrift). More permissive than SIL)
- MIT (example [Couture](https://fontlibrary.org/en/font/couture). More permissive than SIL)
- CC-0 (Example [Aileron](https://fontlibrary.org/en/font/aileron)) **←** This is as permissive as it gets! It expressly waives ALL RIGHTS. So you could modify, rename and CLAIM rights on the new font!

Comment: Note that waiving all rights (essentially disowning) is not legally possible everywhere. Some jurisdictions have inherent copyright which is inalienable.

Comment: Thats why cc, its a legal hoop. It is its a way to make licence to have properties of PD. Surely you can make licenses in any jurisdiction if so you can make same clauses as PD. @JanusBahsJacquet

Answer (score 1):

## When in doubt, read the license

> [SIL Open Font License] enables font authors to release their work under a common license that allows use, bundling, modification and redistribution.

That's about as open as it gets.

Comment: " the Font Software, subject to the following conditions:

1) Neither the Font Software nor any of its individual components,
in Original or Modified Versions, may be sold by itself."  So no you cant sell just the font!

Comment: I'm not aware of any font license that allows you to download for free, then turn around and sell it. The OP is asking about using the font in a product, which OFL allows.

Comment: I found several

Comment: It allows download -> resell? That's just weird.

Comment: Sure [MIT](http://opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php) and CC-0 allow that. CC-0 allows you to modify and claim all rights too.